# Why does my void function don't return the right value? (Newbie to c++)

Tags: c++

As you can see below, my function doesn't return the right value in int main() but it does in the function itself. I'm a newbie to c++, can anyone explain to me why or what's the problem? Thanks!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int a[100],n;

void citire(int n)
{
    int a[100];
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++) {  // the for loop
        cin >> a[i];  // entering the numbers for each
    }
    cout << a[5] << endl; // returns the right number
}

int main()
{
    cout << "n= "; cin >> n; // how many numbers should the vector have.
    citire(n); // me calling the function
    cout << a[5]; // returns 0
}
```

Comment: The array `a[]` is redeclared in function `citire`. Just remove it.

Comment: It happends because your function uses array, defined in your function scope.

Comment: Please go to your text-books (or get [some good ones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282) if you don't have any yet) and read about *scope*.

Comment: you are confusing "return" and "print on the screen". Those are two completely different things. `// returns the right number` --> no the function does not return anything its return type is `void`

Comment: Your void function, by definition, doesn't return anything. That's what the `void` in `void citire(int n)` means.

Answer (score 0):

Variable shadowing, where variables in different scopes have the same name. `int a[100]` inside the function `citire` is allocated on the stack will not persist when it falls out of scope at the end of the function, it's a different array to the global `int a[100]`.

Comment: nitpick: Its not just "different scopes". There is no shadowing in `{ int x; } { int x; }`

Answer (score 0):

You have two different variables, a local variable and a global variable, but as you have given both of them the same name, you don't see that difference. Let me show you in a clearer way what you have programmed:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int global_a[100],n;

void citire(int n)
{
int local_a[100];
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++) {  // the for loop
    cin >> local_a[i];  // entering the numbers for each
}
cout << local_a[5] << endl; // returns the right number
}

int main()
{
cout << "n= "; cin >> n; // how many numbers should the vector have.
citire(n); // me calling the function
cout << global_a[5]; // returns 0
}
```

Now, you tell me, where did you store any variable in the array `global_a`?

In order to avoid this, you might do the following:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int global_a[100],n;

void citire(int n)
{
// int a[100]; don't declare a local variable, so while referring to "a",
//             the global variable will be used:
for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++) {  // the for loop
    cin >> global_a[i];  // entering the numbers for each
}
cout << global_a[5] << endl; // returns the right number
}

int main()
{
cout << "n= "; cin >> n; // how many numbers should the vector have.
citire(n); // me calling the function
cout << global_a[5]; // returns 0
}
```

For your information, the prefixes "local_" and "global_" are just there for clarification purposes. In the last example, you might just write "a" instead of "global_a", the result will be the same.